# *ngIf with compound conditionals performance

Tags: angular

It is known that calling a function in a *ngIf may be bad for performance, as it will be evaluated in every change detection cycle. Instead, it is recommended the use of primitive (number, boolean,..) or immutable values.

My question is if compound conditionals in a *ngIf are treated in the same way. I guess that it is also executed in each change detection, but I would like to confirm it.

For example:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: itemById">
    <button *ngIf="item.showAction && otherComponentCondition">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it depends a bit on what 'otherComponentCondition is? Because there really is only the actual components for this current template (everything else is out of scope)..? And seeing the condition doesn't seem to be a function call - there is no issue right?

Comment: Hi MikeOne, thanks. In the example, `otherComponentCondition` is not a function, it is a primitive variable, just to represent the idea.

Comment: Every expression in the template is evaluated at each change detection. Calling a function is not inherently a problem. The problem is if this function is complex and takes a long time to return its result.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, thank you. I bought a book from your Ninja Squad, great content by the way :) . Considering a smart component that has a ngFor and it's items with ngIf with simple expressions, isn't it be bad yet? I mean, usually for this situations I prepare a custom model (representing the iterable item, with the conditions) Then in the service subscription or onInit method I pre-fill all the variables, so this way it will not have expressions.

Comment: Thanks. Sure, that's *more* efficient. But it can also sometimes add complexity (and bugs), that is unnecessary because calling a method from the template is efficient *enough*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will be reevaluated during each Change Detection Cycle. You can proof that by using a `get` function as a property accessor and console log there.

The best practice not to call functions in expression bindings is mostly because functions tend to get more complex more easily.

Performance-wise, it would be best to not even use compound conditionals but instead use a dedicated variable, changing it when one of the compounds change. That is, as a side note, also the reason reactive programming is so popular with angular.

I added a simple [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jerryd) with that example.

Comment: Hi pascalpuetz, thank you for you answer. A get function is the same as a normal function, so it fits in the first part of my question. The question was related to compound conditionals that are primitive variables. But as JB Nizet answer, it is still an expression and will be executed the same as a function.

Comment: That is exactly what I said.